# Chef recipe database specifies a downlevel MySQL. How should I handle that?

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am using the latest MySQL Chef recipe to install MySQL server. I want to create a database next. The database recipe specifies MySQL ~> 5.0.

How does one deal with those version dependencies?  I can try to change the dependency for the database recipe and see whether it will still work, but that does not feel right.

What is considered best practice for that?

Answer (score 0):

Its unclear if you're talking about mysql version or cookbook versions.

But I'll assume you're talking about cookbooks.

Database cookbook depends on mysql cookbook in version 5.0.x which may install mysql in version 5 to 5.6. 
The mysql cookbook has been bump to 6 (major change), it means it has breaking changes with previous major version.

The database cookbook was not tested (or tested and failed) with mysql cookbook in V6.

For the global 'how to deal with that' the best answer in my point of view is to have a wrapper cookbook for your database which will depend on the database cookbook.

That will take care to install mysql and what is needed for your DB when you call your recipe (you may tweak mysql install by attributes in your wrapper cookbook and include specific recipes not in default path if you need them).

I think your main problem here is seeing the mysql install and the db creation as two separate things but in fact the mysql server install is just a prerequisite of your database creation.

Comment: Thank you for the information. If I use the mysql 6.0 cookbook how would I create a database and populate it? Shell calls to mysql?

Comment: I would more recommend flyway or other do schema manager driven by Chef